# MySQL Query to join two tables together, and get one row with combined data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a poorly modeled database, and there are two tables (`groupowner` and `groupmembers`) with almost identical data.  I want to create a view that combines them and groups them by user.

With the following query...

```
 SELECT 'group' AS resourceType, gm.gid AS resource_id, gm.personid AS account_id, false AS isManager, true AS isMember
 FROM data.groupmembers gm
     UNION
 SELECT 'group' AS resourceType, gn.gid AS resource_id, gn.owner AS account_id, true AS isManager, false AS isMember
 FROM data.groupowner gn
     ORDER BY resource_id ASC, account_id ASC;
```

...I get something like this:

```
resourceType | resource_id | account_id | isManager | isMember
------------ | ----------- | ---------- | --------- | --------
group        | 105         | 506        | 1         | 0
group        | 105         | 506        | 0         | 1
etc...
```

..when what I want is this (combined from both tables, or one or the other):

```
resourceType | resource_id | account_id | isManager | isMember
------------ | ----------- | ---------- | --------- | --------
group        | 105         | 506        | 1         | 1
etc...
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with a MySQL query?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY on the UNION's result, with MAX on isManager  and isMember.

Comment: @jarlh - Wow okay, that was exactly correct.  What a "duh" moment for me.  Worked great.

Comment: Good to hear it worked!

Comment: 'group' is a string. \`group\` could be a column name - but it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @Strawberry - yeah, that column is a bit superfluous in the context of the question.  I should have not included it in the question.

Comment: Similarly, true and false are also reserved words. Given that (to a rough approximation) there are some 1.5 million words in the English language, and the creators of MySQL have seen fit to reserve just 220 of them (approximately), you've really hit the jackpot on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `join` rather than a `union all`.  Assuming that all owners are members, this should work *and* is "view" compatible in MySQL:

```
SELECT 'group' AS resourceType, gm.gid AS resource_id, gm.personid AS account_id,
       (gn.personid is not null) AS isManager, true AS isMember
FROM data.groupmembers gm LEFT JOIN
     data.groupowner gn
     ON gm.gid = gn.gid and
        gm.personid = gn.personid;
```

An alternative method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select gm.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from data.groupowner gn
                where gm.gid = gn.gid and gm.personid = gn.personid
       ) as IsManager
from data.groupmembers;
```

If owners are members, I'm not sure why you need the "isMember" column.

EDIT:

If owners are not members, then you have a challenge getting view-compatible logic.  But, this should work:

```
SELECT 'group' AS resourceType, gm.gid AS resource_id, gm.personid AS account_id,
       (gn.personid is not null) AS isManager, true AS isMember
FROM data.groupmembers gm LEFT JOIN
     data.groupowner gn
     ON gm.gid = gn.gid and
        gm.personid = gn.personid
UNION ALL
SELECT 'group', gn.gid, gn.personid,
       true, false
FROM data.groupowner gn
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM data.groupmembers
                  WHERE gm.gid = gn.gid and gm.personid = gn.personid
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortunately, that assumption is not correct (the data is indeed modeled poorly!).  Sometimes a manager is not a member and vice versa...

Comment: Yes, I just tried a sub-query and learned they are not allowed in MySQL views.  Your EDIT works like a champ, though.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @caseyamcl . . . To be precise, subqueries are not allowed in the `from` clause of a MySQL view.  They are allowed in the `select` and `where` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below query for desire output

```
SELECT resourceType, resource_id, account_id, sum(isManager), sum(isMember) from
( SELECT 'group' AS resourceType, gm.gid AS resource_id, gm.personid AS account_id, 0 AS isManager, 1 AS isMember
 FROM data.groupmembers gm
     UNION
 SELECT 'group' AS resourceType, gn.gid AS resource_id, gn.owner AS account_id, 1 AS isManager, 0 AS isMember
 FROM data.groupowner gn
     ORDER BY resource_id ASC, account_id ASC) temp
group by  resource_id, account_id;
```

Comment: I tried something very similar, and it worked, but unfortunately, you cannot create views from sub queries.

Comment: Correct MySQL's limitation is that one cannot create a view from such a select statement which contains subquery. This limitation can be easily overcome if one creates one view for subquery and then use this view for creation of originally wanted view. so you will have to create 2 views.